# Get time object was created

Tags: objective-c, ios, timestamp

Is there a way to get the time an object was instantiated without having to store a timestamp date object in it to recall?

I'm using a class from a framework and I want a timestamp on when it was created without having to extend or create a wrapper for it just for a date object.

Comment: I'm curious why you want this. Debugging purposes?

Comment: I wanted to sort a set of objects by the time they were created

Comment: Not to pry, but again... why? There might be a completely different solution to whatever you're hoping to do with this information.

Comment: I have a set of objects in core-data that I need to maintain creation order and when you pull things out of core-data you lose that ordering, so I'm timestamping the objects so that I can sort by that after I've pulled them out of core-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect it to be recorded.  What is important from a class perspective is how many references it has.  No matter when it was created, once it has no references, it is garbage.  When it was created is of no interest to the runtime.

Comment: thanks, figured it would be something like that. Ended up just making a wrapper class.